# How do I export existing schema in Bookshelfjs, Knex.js?

Tags: migration, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I am mapping Bookshelf.js to an existing schema. I would like to start managing the existing schema with Knex migrations.

Is there a way to export the existing schema as a migration, so that I have a starting point moving forward?

Or do I have to create the migration files manually. (Not the end of the world, but would be nice to export)